# How to wait for command execution to complete in eshell

Tags: eshell, process

I guess I don't quite understand how to write commands for eshell. I am using the form:

```
(defun eshell/command ()" " (interactive)
  (insert "command")
  (eshell-send-input))
```

When I do this it prints the *command* and then the prompt, even though the command has not finished executing. I can force the printing of the prompt after I send the commands, but this happens immediately as well, not after the command has completed.

I would like to see some visual indication that the command has finished. I kind of assume there is an eshell elisp function that will wait for the command to finish (like `wait` in bash) so I can force the prompt, but I can't find it. Generally is seems you may want to wait for the command to finish before returning from the function. It seems like this would be a common problem. Can someone point me to the obvious which I am not seeing? Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, I spent several hours trying calling (and reading the source for) various eshell functions and I still haven't figured it out.  My use-case was an eshell function wrapper which would either use Lisp or call out to an external command depending on its arguments. In the latter case (calling external command), the eshell function would finish without waiting on the process (I would've thought surely I could call eshell's own functions like `eshell-external-command` to do it, but nope).

Comment: From my position of relative ignorance, the best I could do is read the source starting at `eshell-send-input` to figure out where a normal command goes, because following all the code and data paths from there would inevitably reveal how Eshell normally decides to wait for a command, and thus how to hook into that. But that's an endeavor I haven't had the time and patience to undertake. So even though I don't have much rep to offer on this Emacs stack, I'm very tempted to put a bounty on this question. If there's anyone who needs that as the tipping point to try to figure it out, reply @ me.